Naming of file while saving with extension
How can I save a file with the name as: oldname+"_new"+extension in an elegant way?
I currently do:
ext = os.path.splitext(file)[1]
output_file = (root+'/'+ os.path.splitext(file)[0]+"_new"+ext)
#or output_file = (os.path.join(root, os.path.splitext(file)[0])+'_new'+ext)

with open(output_file, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
      file.write(text)

(with the help of Python: how to retain the file extension when renaming files with os? , but not duplicate)
--
I use Python 3.12.2

What version of python are you using? If at least 3.6, f-strings make it much more readable.

You're making two calls to the same splittext function so at the very least can save those to variables filename, ext = splittext(.. but these are all trivial changes

added version (3.12.x) to question @MGP

pathlib.Path is preferred in modern code for a more OO approach.
For example:
from pathlib import Path

def makenew(filename: Path, new: str = "_new") -> Path:
    return filename.parent / (filename.stem + new + filename.suffix)

print(makenew(Path("/Users/SIGHUP/foo.txt")))

Output:
/Users/SIGHUP/foo_new.txt


filename.parent / ... is already a Path object; you don't need to explicitly call Path to create the return value.
